# =One or Another value

Tags: random, excel-formula

I would like to make a formula that chooses one or another value from the formula itself. So for example the end result would look like that:

```
apple
apple
orange
apple
orange
orange
orange
orange
```

And formula within the cell might look something like that:
=random(apple OR orange). Then I would just drag it across all the cells I need to fill it randomly with either apple or orange.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Use CHOOSE() with RANDBETWEEN:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"Apple","Orange")
```